# SQL Server 2005 Report Manager - data source connection info deleted?

Tags: sql-server-2005, reporting-services

Just started a new job and one of my duties is to create/alter reports and make them accessible on our report server for the rest of the company.  I've created a new report (from an existing report) in Visual Studio 2005 and it works fine in VS.  After I Upload the file to the report server using Microsoft SQL Server Report Manager and try to view the report it says "The report server cannot process the report. The data source connection information has been deleted. (rsInvalidDataSourceReference)"

I checked in Properties > Data Sources and the first option "A shared data source" is selected with a alert next to it saying "The shared data source reference is no longer valid".  The odd thing is that the original report that I used to create this one has the same alert and same settings, but it executes fine. They are very similar - original reports by year and the new one is by month.

I'd really appreciate any help i can get on this one as I don't have anyone in the company I can lean on.  I'm very unfamiliar with these applications so it could be that I just need some basic first steps to troubleshoot this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Did you upload the datasource as well?

Comment: No it was just the report file and there was only one upload field available. I wasn't sure that i had to since the original report works fine.  What I ended up doing was just providing the data source with my DB credentials, it worked but doesn't seem right since it's the only report with credentials specified like that.